# How to set the dropdown value by clicking on a table row

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to find out a way to dynamically/remotely change the selected value of a dropdown-menu by clicking on a table row, preferably located on another html page.

The code below shows an attempt to get it to work, but the value of the dropdown-menu gets blank when clicking on any table row.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table">
<tr><td>option1</td></tr>
<tr><td>option2</td></tr>
<tr><td>option3</td></tr> 
</table>

<script>
  // Get references to the dropdown and table
  const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('#table');

  // Add a click event listener to each table row
  tableRows.forEach(row => {
  row.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Get the value associated with the clicked row
  const selectedValue = this.getAttribute('data-value');

  // Set the dropdown's value to the selected value
  dropdown.value = selectedValue;
  });
});
```

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because:

1- You are assigning the event to the table, not the table-cell(td).

2- No `data-value` attribute is defined for the table-cells.

Hence the selectedValue is null.

```js
        const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('#table td');
// td is added to the css selector

        tableCells.forEach(cell => {
            cell.addEventListener('click', function () {
                const selectedValue = this.getAttribute('data-value');
                dropdown.value = selectedValue;
            });
        });
```

```css
#table td {cursor: pointer;}  /* optional to show the table-cell is clickable */
```

```html
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table">
        <tr><td data-value="option1">option1</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-value="option2">option2</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-value="option3">option3</td></tr>
    </table>
```

**Edit: Case when the dropdown is in another page**

Assuming the dropdown resides in a separate page (`77294082_B.html`), we add a simple function to change the selected-value of dropdown so we can call it from the opener window (`77294082_A.html`).

**77294082_B.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>77294082_B/how-to-set-the-dropdown-value-by-clicking-on-a-table-row</title>
    <script>
        function set_selectedValue(vlu) {
            document.getElementById("dropdown").value = vlu;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="dropdown">
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

In the opener window where the table resides, we add an event listener to load event to automatically open page `77294082_B.html` and then display the table. this is to ensure page B is loaded before user can click on table.
In page A, the `set_selectedValue` of page B is invoked when a cell is clicked.

**77294082_A.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>77294082_A/how-to-set-the-dropdown-value-by-clicking-on-a-table-row</title>
    <style>
        #table td {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table" style="visibility:hidden;">
        <tr><td data-value="option1">option1</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-value="option2">option2</td></tr>
        <tr><td data-value="option3">option3</td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var windowB;
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            windowB = window.open("77294082_B.html");
            windowB.addEventListener("load", function () {
                table.style.visibility = "visible";
            });
        });

        const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
        const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll("#table td");

        tableCells.forEach(cell => {
            cell.addEventListener("click", function () {
                const selectedValue = this.getAttribute("data-value");
                windowB.set_selectedValue(selectedValue);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Shahram! It works!
Now the next step is to change the dropdown that's located on another URL...

Comment: You are welcome. It seems by `dropdown located on another page` you mean this another page is the action of a form on current page. Am I correct ?

Comment: I meant that the clickable table is located on one page, while the dropdown is located on another page. 
Both pages share the same origin (have the same host).
Tanks.

Comment: AFAIK though it is possible to access elements, it is not possible to run javascript code on another independent page, maybe there is a technique I am not aware of. But if you open this another page with `window. Open` then you have access to it and can run a script on it. I will edit the answer to cover this.

Comment: Thank you again for taking your time Shahram! It works! 
sorry for the delay as I've been very busy with other tasks.