# how to set the value of two dropdowns by clicking on a table row located on another page

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

The code below works fine with everything located on the same page.

But I need the dropdowns to be located on a parent page (window.opener) and the table on the child page (window.open).

Edit:
But I'm still trying to find the right code to pass the function from the child page to the parent page.

```
 parent:

 <select id="dropdown">
 <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
 </select>
 
 <select id="dropdown_2">
 <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
 <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
 </select>

child:

 <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table">
 <tr>
 <th value="">Options</th><th value="">Value</th></tr>
 <tr>
 <td value="option1">Option1</td><td value="value1">Value1</td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td value="option2">Option2</td><td value="value2">Value2</td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td value="option3">Option3</td><td value="value3">Value3</td></tr>
 </table>

<script>
// Get references to the dropdown and table
const dropdowns = document.getElementById('[id^=dropdown]');
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr');

// Add a click event listener to each table row
tableRows.forEach(row => {
row.addEventListener('click', function() {

// Get the value associated with the clicked row
// const selectedValue = this.getAttribute('value');

var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");

// Set the dropdown's value to the selected value
dropdown.value = cells[0].getAttribute("value"); 
dropdown_2.value = cells[1].getAttribute("value");
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: May be a duplicate of [how-to-set-the-dropdown-value-by-clicking-on-a-table-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294082/how-to-set-the-dropdown-value-by-clicking-on-a-table-row)

Comment: No. 
In my previous question the dropdowns and table are in the same page, but in this question the table is located in another page (page 2) and the dropdowns in the page 1.
The other page (page 2) may be an iframe or php.

Comment: The answer to that question is already updated to cover this question.

Comment: Yes, I've suggested one method, but I'm still trying to find the right code to pass the function from the child page to the parent page.
The examples I've found just pass text or values, I couldn't find any example to make the parent page execute a function from the child page.